How to overwrite traefik.yml file on Ubuntu 22.04 when Warden is installed?
I am using Warden stuff on Ubuntu 22.04 and I am having trouble overwriting the ~/.warden/etc/traefik/traefik.yml file.. Each time after restarting a computer, the mentioned file is restored to the original version..
I am wondering how to overwrite the file - I tried to create the necessary traefik.yml inside ~/.config/warden/etc/traefik/traefik.yml folder but it didn't help..
the whole question is to solve the problem of redirection from port 80 to 443 (section entryPoints inside the mentioned file.. I do not want redirection and for some reasons keep port 80 as it is..
